# List of Requests for Volley Multipart Request

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have working VolleyMultipartRequest code which uploads image and doc files to my server. But I have mentioned one problem: I need to send a list of images and docs with one request to my server. I mean, for instance I choose 2 images and 3 doc files and by pressing "Send" button I need to send only one request.

Below the part of my Java code for sending and JSON params for server:

```
//---------------------Map<String, String>
                params.put("orientation", "P");
                params.put("margin", "5");
                params.put("type", "image");
                params.put("copies", "1");
                params.put("width", "" + 150);
                params.put("height", "" + 150);
//-----------------------Map<String, DataPart>
                params.put("file", new DataPart("image1.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapList.get(0))), "image/jpeg"));
```

and my Json

```
file: File
type: "image"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom request, override getByteData method and send your content as bytes. Check this example, it appends two different files in a single request by overriding getByteData:

https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594#file-volleymultipartrequest-java

```
@Override
protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
    Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
    // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
    // for now just get bitmap data from ImageView
    params.put("avatar", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), mAvatarImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));
    params.put("cover", new DataPart("file_cover.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), mCoverImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));

    return params;
}
```